# Firebase Cloud Firestore triggers for Cloud Functions : context.params undefined

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This should be simple but I am not sure what I am missing.
I am trying to recreate the example stated in the docs, modifying only the variable names:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events

Trying to log the value of context.params returns undefined.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

exports.makeUppercase = functions.firestore
  .document("/messages/{documentId}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    console.log(context.params.documentId); // undefined
    console.log(context.params); // undefined
  });
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.4.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.3.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.0.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.0.0",
    "@mui/styles": "^5.0.0",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^4.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "firebase": "^9.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-firebase-hooks": "^3.0.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

What am I missing here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Comment: alright pls find attached